# Illustrator : 'deleting' overlay compound path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made a circle, and above that I put a compound path which I download from internet, a custom B, I want to just take the circle without the custom B, I did it before, let say a circle with star above, if I want to take the circle without star I will use path finder, but it seems not working for compound path any solution?

[image: http://s7.postimage.org/dm28jozvv/bcoin.png]

Comment: see here, I want to have the circle without the B. Cannot use pathfinder remove front, it won't work

Comment: http://s7.postimage.org/dm28jozvv/bcoin.png

Comment: You need to check the objects then. There's no reason Pathfinder > Minus Front (Subtract From Shape Area in CS3) shouldn't work. Make certain your "internet" image doesn't have a clipping mask applied to it or some other construction complexity it doesn't need.

Comment: it didn't work, maybe because it's a compound path, making from many path. I solved them by divide object.

Comment: It should still work fine with compound paths. There must be some other reason the objects are problematic.

Comment: @UmairIbrahim, I tried following in your footsteps to recreate your issue, but I wasn't able to. If you come back to this site and give us some more info we can try and help, but for now I've got to close this question for not having enough information

Answer (score 1):

Objects of the same group won't behave normal using the pathfinder. Having a compound for the B would suffice. I think you don't need to have it in a group or in a group together with the background, respectively other elements.